# Computing Yaw angle from position and velocities

Tags: mobile-robot, dynamics, motion

I have an object to whom I know the x,y,z position, length, width, height, and x,y velocities. Is there a possibility to compute the yaw angle from this information?

Comment: If you know the xyz position of more points of the object, e.g. each corner then yes, there is.

Comment: well if I know that the x and y coordinates corespond to one corner of the object and I know the with and the length

Comment: If you only know the x and y of one corner and width and length (scalars) you cannot calculate orientation

Comment: I also know my yaw and yaw rate, and my speed, doesn't this help somehow?

Comment: In the question you mentioned that you want to compute the yaw...

Comment: well yes, of an object that is in front of me, I understand that it is not possible to compute the yaw just from the parameters I have given, but I maybe I can compute it by knowing some of my motion parameters, like my speed or my yaw or yaw rate (in addition to those already mentioned)

Comment: If you only know the position coordinates of one point (regardless of time dependent coordinates) you cannot compute yaw. You need at least 1 points on the object and their relation to eachother have to be aprioriy known and fixed. I.e. the two upper corners of a rectangle

Comment: I understand,however if I have the x,y,z coordinates of a point on the object and the length and width of the object (plus the other information I mentioned ) how can compute the yaw angle ?

Comment: this is a different question. Post it as a new question and I sure it will be aswered

Comment: On stack exchange, comments are not intended for extended discussions, for that use [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. Comments should be considered ephemeral, any comment which no longer actively helps to improve a question or answer may be deleted at any time to *tidy up* a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean by the "x,y,z positions and x,y velocities" just for one point of the object for example: ***The Mass Center*** or ***The Geometrical Center*** so the answer is **No it is not possible**, because it's possible for any point of the object to have any value for this parameters "x,y,z positions and x,y velocities" for different Yaw angles
but if you have another constrain or information about the object it may become possible to compute the yaw angle from this information